# Changing Resolution in ffmpeg output to display video stream in Android

Tags: android, video, android-ndk, ffmpeg, sdl-2

I'm trying to change the camera output(Resolution:640 x 480),to 1024 x 720 and render the video frames in the Android screen.Is it possible to do this video conversion with ffmpeg and SDL libraries?If so is there any API's avaliable in ffmepeg codec libraries to do the same?

Here is the code where i got the output for 640 x 480 resolution:

```
//Registering all the formats:
av_register_all();
AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx=NULL;
int             i, videoStream;
AVCodecContext  *pCodecCtx=NULL;
AVCodec         *pCodec=NULL;
AVFrame         *pFrame;
AVPacket        packet;
int             frameFinished;
SDL_Texture         *bmp;
SDL_Renderer *renderer;
SDL_Window  *screen;

if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO)) {
    LOGD( "Could not initialize SDL - %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    SDL_Quit();
    exit(1);
}
LOGD(" SDL Initialized..");

screen = SDL_CreateWindow("Window", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 0, 0,
        SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN);
LOGD("SDL Screen Created ..");

renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(screen,-1,SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_TARGETTEXTURE);
LOGD("Rendering Created...");

bmp = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer,     SDL_PIXELFORMAT_IYUV,SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING,640,480);
LOGD("Texture created;");

SDL_RenderSetLogicalSize(renderer,640,480);
// Open video file
if(avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx,"Filename", NULL,NULL)!=0)
    LOGD("Cannot open the File");

pFormatCtx->interrupt_callback.callback = decode_interrupt_cb;

// Retrieve stream information
if(avformat_find_stream_info(pFormatCtx,NULL)<0)
    LOGD("Cannot retrive Stream info");
  // Couldn't find stream information

videoStream=-1;
for(i=0; i<pFormatCtx->nb_streams; i++)
if(pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type==AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
      videoStream=i;
    break;
}
if(videoStream==-1)
LOGD("Cannot find Video Stream:");
pCodecCtx=pFormatCtx->streams[videoStream]->codec;
// Find the decoder for the video stream
pCodec=avcodec_find_decoder(pCodecCtx->codec_id);
if(pCodec==NULL) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Unsupported codec!\n");
  LOGD("Unable to find the decoder");
    // Codec not found
 }
 // Open codec
 if(avcodec_open2(pCodecCtx, pCodec,NULL)<0)
  LOGD("Unable to OPEN Codec");
  // Could not open codec

 // Allocate video frame
  pFrame=avcodec_alloc_frame();

  i=0;
  while(av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet)>=0) {
        // Is this a packet from the video stream?
        if(packet.stream_index==videoStream) {
      // Decode video frame
      avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &frameFinished,&packet);

      // Did we get a video frame?
      if(frameFinished) {
          //----------------Code for Displaying
          SDL_UpdateYUVTexture(bmp, NULL, pFrame->data[0],
                                    pFrame->linesize[0], pFrame->data[1], pFrame->linesize[1],
                                    pFrame->data[2], pFrame->linesize[2]);

                            retcl = SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
                            retcopy = SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, bmp, NULL, NULL);
                            SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
          //-----------------
      }
    }

        // Free the packet that was allocated by av_read_frame
    av_free_packet(&packet);
  }

  // Free the RGB image
  av_free(buffer);

  // Free the YUV frame
  av_free(pFrame);

  // Close the codec
  avcodec_close(pCodecCtx);

  // Close the video file
  avformat_close_input(&pFormatCtx);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg uses a "filtergraph" to apply filters like scaling, cropping etc. If you look into the [filtering video example](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/filtering_video.c) you will see how filters are applied programmatically. If you can integrate that example into your code, then all you have to do is to change the string - filter_descr - to have the video scaled to your desired resolution.

Filters are defined the same way as with the stand-alone program. See the [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Video-Filters) for more details.